# mean init stops after "What would you name your mean app?"

Tags: node.js, mean.io

I followed the instructions on learn.mean.io to setup 2 virtual linux machines to generate mean apps.

The problem on both machines is that mean init stops after i hit enter on the question:
*? What would you name your mean app? myApp*

after that mean init stops without error but did not create the directory to cd into.

any ideas why?
is there a log i can check?

both systems:
Ubuntu 14.04
node v4.4.4
npm 3.8.9
mongo 3.2.6
mean 0.12.9
gulp 3.9.1
bower 1.7.9

Comment: same is happening with me!

Comment: did you start trying today, maybe a temporary bug?

Comment: I got this today,i was trying this for first time!

Answer (score 1):

I just found on github that this is a bug, you can install an earlier version until the issue is resolved

sudo npm install -g mean-cli@0.11.1